# I need help on Sharepoint to show a library document folder based in which project are selected

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I'm having a big issue trying to link a specific folder to a specific project on my site. I'll show exactly what i need (i don't know if its possible) on the images:

I have a list of project on the home page:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEGyg.png)

When i click in one of the projects, the site redirect me to the page of that project:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg0xz.png)

And i created a documents library with folders that have the same name of the projects i have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAuAB.png)

What i need?
I need to show the documents library on the left side of the selected project and when i click on the "documents library" the only folder to show is the folder based on the selected project:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sDni.png)

how can i do thar?? Is it possible?

Thanks so much! I appreciate any help!

I tried to create subsites of each project, but i cant link to the projects too. I tried from power automate but i failed too.